# Seeking a PHP script to filter an RSS feed

Tags: php, rss, filter

I have about 50 feeds (and growing) that I would like to filter before adding them to Google Reader. Each of the feeds will be filtered for the same keywords. If a keyword match is found, that item will be removed from the feed. Basically I'm just trying to eliminate some noise.

I know I can do this with Yahoo Pipes, but I'm looking for a self-hosted solution.

I'd like to pass a feed to a script on my server. That script will filter out unwanted feed items based on a list of defined keywords. The filtered feed will be the result. I plan to then add the feed to Google Reader.

(BTW, why doesn't Google Reader have filters like Gmail?)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a RSS library like [Simplepie](http://simplepie.org/). From there, writing the filter logic should be easy-peasy.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ReFilter](http://re.rephrase.net/filter/?p=iaq). Looks nice.